# What will i use? Will be? would be? can be? Could be?

Tags: modal-verbs

> Before the seeds germinated, I did not know what kind of plants they __________.
>
> A. Will be
>   B. would be
>   C. can be
>   D. could be

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a kind of "Future in the past" sentence construction
for these kind of constructs the correct usage is "would be"

More information for your reference:
http://www.englishpage.com/verbpage/futureinpast.html